# Python error logging

Tags: python, error-logging

I'd like to find a way to log every error that forces the python interpreter to quit to be saved to a file as well as being printed to the screen.  The reason I would like to do this is that I want to keep stats on the types of errors I make while writing code, with an eye towards finding ways to avoid mistakes I make commonly in the future.

I've been attempting to do this by writing a wrapper for the python interpreter using the subprocess module.  Basically, it runs the python interpreter, captures any output, parse and saves it to a file, prints the output, and use matplotlib to make some summary figures.  However, I'm having a problem getting output from my wrapper script in real time.  For example, if the script I'm running is:

```
import os  
import time

for x in range(10):  
    print "testing"  
    time.sleep(10)
```

and I'm using subprocess.Popen() with p.communicate(), the wrapper will wait 100 seconds, and then print all of the output.  I'd like the wrapper to be as invisible as possible - ideally in this case it would print "testing" once every ten seconds.

If someone could point me towards a good way of doing this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can simply replace `sys.excepthook` with your own function.  You can read about it in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

Basically, it allows you to customize what happens when an exception percolates up to the point of forcing the Python interpreter to quit.  You use it like this:

```
import sys

def my_excepthook(type, value, tb):
    # you can log the exception to a file here
    print 'In My Exception Handler'

    # the following line does the default (prints it to err)
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb)

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
```

You'll probably also want to look at [the traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html), for formatting the traceback you get.