# Python/Django: automatically log when exceptions occur, including request info

Tags: python, django, exception, logging

I have created a function log_error(request, traceback), which I call in my exceptions. This writes error information to the database. Now, before I open up every one of my views and add this in an exception handler, is there a way to automatically have all exceptions raise to a function, which then calls this?

I have seen this [Python error logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941543/python-error-logging), which says to write your own version of sys.excepthook. This function is automatically called when there is an exception. I tried this, but my_excepthook was not called even though I copy-pasted the solution into views.py and raised an error. However, I didn't try too hard because it's not getting all the information that I need, anyway.  I also need request so I can log information abut the user, url, etc.

Maybe that's asking too much?

(I'm using Django, but this does not seem like a Django-specific thing) Edit: yes, it is.

Comment: `sys.excepthook` is only called for unhandled exceptions, or those that are re-raised by their handler -- which may be why it didn't appear to work when you tried it. For the most part the only information it has is what it's passed as arguments. You could store additional information someplace and have your version look there for it there.

Comment: [Django can be configured to report all unhandled exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian. The error  way works. I wrote up a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

J.F Sebastian's suggestion worked. This is a Django solution.

In settings.py MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

(I added it as the last one, not sure if this is right or will cause errors down the line. Works for now.)

```
'myapp.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',
```

In myapp.middleware.py:

```
import traceback
class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        log_error(traceback, request)
```

That's it. log_error is my function and writes to the database. It also appears from the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/ that I can get the local variables as well as the request attributes.

Comment: Can you please share, how's your log_error function implemented ? do you log request.META and traceback both as two TextFields(models.TextField) ? Thanks